# How To fix a PPTP VPN client connection (Ubuntu on VirtualBox)

Tags: networking, virtualbox, network-manager, vpn

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox and I'm trying to set up a VPN client. I have configured it with the same settings I use on a Mac and I am able to connect from that without any problem.

When I click on the VPN connections I see the following message pop up after a short delay:

The VPN connection failed.

I've searched around for a solution without any luck. I'm not experienced in these matters at all. I've provided the log in the hope that it helps.

TIA.

```
Feb 17 20:31:05 ubuntu NetworkManager[856]: <info> Starting VPN service 'pptp'...
Feb 17 20:31:05 ubuntu NetworkManager[856]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp), PID 3629
Feb 17 20:31:05 ubuntu NetworkManager[856]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' appeared; activating connections
Feb 17 20:31:05 ubuntu NetworkManager[856]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: init (1)
Feb 17 20:31:05 ubuntu NetworkManager[856]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: starting (3)
Feb 17 20:31:05 ubuntu NetworkManager[856]: <info> VPN connection 'Bioxydyn' (Connect) reply received.
Feb 17 20:31:05 ubuntu pppd[3633]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Feb 17 20:31:05 ubuntu pppd[3633]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Feb 17 20:31:05 ubuntu pppd[3633]: Using interface ppp0
Feb 17 20:31:05 ubuntu pppd[3633]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/0
Feb 17 20:31:05 ubuntu pptp[3636]: nm-pptp-service-3629 log[main:pptp.c:314]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
Feb 17 20:31:05 ubuntu NetworkManager[856]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Feb 17 20:31:05 ubuntu NetworkManager[856]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Feb 17 20:31:05 ubuntu NetworkManager[856]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Feb 17 20:31:05 ubuntu pptp[3653]: nm-pptp-service-3629 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 1 'Start-Control-Connection-Request'
Feb 17 20:31:05 ubuntu pptp[3653]: nm-pptp-service-3629 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:739]: Received Start Control Connection Reply
Feb 17 20:31:05 ubuntu pptp[3653]: nm-pptp-service-3629 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:773]: Client connection established.
Feb 17 20:31:06 ubuntu pptp[3653]: nm-pptp-service-3629 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 7 'Outgoing-Call-Request'
Feb 17 20:31:06 ubuntu pptp[3653]: nm-pptp-service-3629 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:858]: Received Outgoing Call Reply.
Feb 17 20:31:06 ubuntu pptp[3653]: nm-pptp-service-3629 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:897]: Outgoing call established (call ID 0, peer's call ID 10009).
Feb 17 20:31:36 ubuntu pppd[3633]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Feb 17 20:31:36 ubuntu pppd[3633]: Connection terminated.
Feb 17 20:31:36 ubuntu NetworkManager[856]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Feb 17 20:31:36 ubuntu avahi-daemon[661]: Withdrawing workstation service for ppp0.
Feb 17 20:31:36 ubuntu NetworkManager[856]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Feb 17 20:31:36 ubuntu pppd[3633]: Modem hangup
Feb 17 20:31:36 ubuntu pptp[3636]: nm-pptp-service-3629 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:204]: short read (-1): Input/output error
Feb 17 20:31:36 ubuntu pptp[3636]: nm-pptp-service-3629 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:216]: pppd may have shutdown, see pppd log
Feb 17 20:31:36 ubuntu pppd[3633]: Exit.
Feb 17 20:31:36 ubuntu pptp[3653]: nm-pptp-service-3629 log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:234]: Closing connection (unhandled)
Feb 17 20:31:36 ubuntu NetworkManager[856]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Feb 17 20:31:36 ubuntu NetworkManager[856]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: stopped (6)
Feb 17 20:31:36 ubuntu NetworkManager[856]: <info> VPN plugin state change reason: 0
Feb 17 20:31:36 ubuntu NetworkManager[856]: <info> Policy set 'Wired connection 1' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Feb 17 20:31:36 ubuntu pptp[3653]: nm-pptp-service-3629 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
Feb 17 20:31:36 ubuntu pptp[3653]: nm-pptp-service-3629 log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:79]: Closing connection (call state)
Feb 17 20:31:36 ubuntu NetworkManager[856]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
Feb 17 20:31:41 ubuntu NetworkManager[856]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' disappeared
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it with this:

1. Login as root or do su or `sudo su`.
2. `touch /etc/modules-load.d/netfilter.conf`
3. Edit `/etc/modules-load.d/netfilter.conf`

*netfilter.conf:*

```
nf_nat_pptp
nf_conntrack_pptp
nf_conntrack_proto_gre
```

5. Save file and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Just resurrecting this because it was part of my search earlier this week, but the posted solution didn't help.

Fox Mulder is correct about the cause of the problem - gre/pptp packets are not being routed correctly, but the problem in this case is actually the VirtualBox virtual network interfaces.

Using a NAT network interface, you cannot route pptp or gre correctly.

Edit your VBox config to use a bridged connection and everything should work just fine (assuming your host OS and all other network devices up the chain are passing gre and pptp traffic correctly).